# Missing full stop in help center for answer bans

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, post-ban

I've seen a bug on the page *[Why are answers no longer being accepted from my account?](https://mathoverflow.net/help/answer-bans)*.

The one part of this page is:

> The only way to end a posting block is to positively contribute to the site; automatic bans never expire or "time out". Begin by fixing your existing answers; do not just post the same answer again or delete all of your existing answers. All answers are expected to be useful to future visitors, in addition to the original asker, so keep the following tips in mind when improving your answers:
>
> - Answer the question. Do not post an answer simply to say "thanks" or "I'm having this problem, too"
> - Do not post follow-up questions as answers. Ask a new question instead.
> - Use correct spelling, punctuation, and grammar to the best of your ability.
> - Provide context for links. Link-only answers are not good answers.

The first bullet point misses a full stop at the end. It should be written as follows:

> Answer the question. Do not post an answer simply to say "thanks" or "I'm having this problem, too".

Can this bug be fixed?

Comment: This applies to the default Answer Bans entry in the Help Center (see, e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/answer-bans).

Comment: (The [cross-Atlantic](https://grammarist.com/usage/full-stop-period/) fight: *"In American English, period is the term for the punctuation mark used to end declarative sentences. In British English, the mark is usually called a full stop. Neither term is right or wrong. They’re just different ways of saying the same thing."*)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The missing period has now been added in, bringing this sentence (and this problem) to a close.